# How to do a rolling restart of mysql ndb cluster in an automated manner

Tags: mysql-cluster

Is there any way that I can have single point of control to perform cluster activities such as rolling restart without logging into each specific node such and Management, API and restarting each one manually.

Answer (score 0):

This 'single point of control' would be the management server:

Run 'ndb_mgm' on the management server, or 'ndb_mgm --ndb-mgmd-host=' from another host.

To restart the management server:
ndb_mgm> 1 restart

To restart the first node:
ndb_mgm> 2 restart

To restart the second node:
ndb_mgm> 3 restart

... and so on.

Note that i am assuming node#1 as the management server node, and data nodes starting with number 2. If you